# Find the number of substring of a string that satisfy a criteria

Tags: java, string, algorithm, testing, substring

Question:
Given a string a, find the number of subsegments of the string that contain at least one vowel AND one consonant. For example : input "blue" will have number of subsgments = 1, "hackerrank" will return number of segments = 3 ("ha","cker","rank") each will contain at least one consonant and one vowel.

Here is my code in Java

```
public static int segments(String password){
      int numbersegments = 0;
      int vowel = 0;
      int consonant = 0;
      for(int index = 0; index < password.length();index++){
            if(password.charAt(index) == 'a' || password.charAt(index) == 'e' ||
                    password.charAt(index) == 'i' || password.charAt(index) == 'u'
                    || password.charAt(index) == 'o'    ){
                  vowel++;
            }
            else
                consonant++;
            if(vowel >= 1 && consonant >= 1){
                numbersegments++;
                vowel = 0;
                consonant = 0;

            }
      }
      return numbersegments;
}
```

I run the test cases with code above and it shows 5 out of 15 ouputs are correct. Unfortunately i can't see the input for those incorrect testcases so there is no way i can see the missing logic for my code above to run 100% correct on all cases. Maybe  i didn't take into account certain edge cases but i cannot think of any. Is there any flaw of my code above ? Is there any missing cases that i forget to take into account ? Thank you

Comment: @kungho you did not take into consideration CAPs, special characters & numbers. you check small letter vowels only. so "blUE" does not work for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think it will work

```
public static int segments(String password){
  int numbersegments = 0;
  int vowel = 0;
  int consonant = 0;

  password = password.toLowerCase(); 

  for(int index = 0; index < password.length();index++){
        if(password.charAt(index) == 'a' || password.charAt(index) == 'e' ||
                password.charAt(index) == 'i' || password.charAt(index) == 'u'
                || password.charAt(index) == 'o'  ){
              vowel++;
        }
        else if(password.charAt(index)>='a' && password.charAt(index)<='z')
            consonant++;

        if(vowel >= 1 && consonant >= 1){
            numbersegments++;
            vowel = 0;
            consonant = 0;
        }
  }
  return numbersegments;
}
```

You did not take into consideration CAPs, special characters & numbers. you check small letter vowels only.

Comment: Yes i should have taken into account of upper case letter but how taking into consideration of  special characters and numbers is going change logic of my code since my for loop didn't exclude any of them when i check for condition

Comment: 'a1' does not meet your conditions but it will return 1 from your function.

Comment: `password = password.toLowerCase();` is this line sufficient to handle CAPs, special characters & numbers !?

Comment: @SafinGhoghabori Yes